# Best way to render nested FormArrays via *ngFor

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-pipe, angular-changedetection

I've been doing a project with huge forms lately and I've run into performance problems. After some researching, I wondered, what is the better way to select nested `FormArrays` from a reactive form into the `*ngFor` statement.

For example, I have such a structure of the form, where `...` means N items of FormGroup (inside FormArray) and FormControl (inside FormGroups):

```
MainFormGroup {
    ParentFormArray {
       ...
       FormGroup {
           ...
           NestedFormArray {
                ...
                FormGroup { ... }
                ...
           }
           ...
       }
       ...
    }
}
```

In Angular 15 I can't render FormArrays this way, as it can be found on older StackOverflow questions:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of form.controls['ParentFormArray'].controls; let i = index"
```

Because `controls` does not exist inside `AbstractControl`. So we need to tell template that `ParentFormArray` is an instance of `FormArray` directly.

To do that, we have several options (these only the ones I've found):

1. make a getter in `.ts` that returns `FormArray`, but this won't allow us to put a parameter inside (for example, parent `FormGroup` of the `NestedFormArray`
2. make a method that returns `FormArray` and can get a parameter to return nested FormArrays of a specific FormGroup (which is also nested inside parent FormArray)
3. make a pipe for getting these items as FormArray

As I know, first two options are bad, because getter and method will be called on every ChangeDetection run. But what about pipes? Is this option more preferable in case of reactive forms?

For example pipe I've written for testing purposes:

```
@Pipe({ name: "getArray", pure: true })
export class GetArrayPipe {
    transform (formGroup: AbstractControl, path?: string): FormArray | null {
        return path ? <FormArray>formGroup.get(path) : <FormArray>formGroup;
    }
}
```

And using it like this:

```
for parent:
<accordion *ngFor="let parentItem of (ParentFormArray | getArray).controls; let i = index"> // parentItem there would be a FormGroup instance

and for nested:
<accordion *ngFor="let nestedItem of (parentItem | getArray:'NestedFormArray').controls; let i = index"> // get controls of the nested FormArray of the parent FormGroup
```

Or is there a better way to render such multi-level forms?

P.S. tested with `console.log` and the result of pipe is great: with methods or getters `log` is being called dozens of times per every click (every ChangeDetection with Default strategy), while pipe is being called only 1 time on the initial render.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best option so far was to use pure pipes. Using this option, angular doesn't need to extract `FormArray`s from `FormGroup`s every change detection cycle

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).